# Reload component after POST api VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, api-platform.com

I have problems to reload components in my app VueJS with NUXTJS.
I have a page in my app and this page called a component “CustomerCard”.

I use a fetch to talk to my API and have all my customers. It works very well when I arrive in this page.

I have a modal with a form and when I add a customer via this modal, the customer is recorded in my database. It works but when the modal closing, I don’t know how to re-render the component… (when I click on my navigation it does not work neither)

```html
<template>
  <div >
    <a-button type="primary" @click="showModal">
      Add a customer
    </a-button>
    <a-modal
      title="Name :"
      :visible="visible"
      :confirm-loading="confirmLoading"
      @ok="handleOk"
      @cancel="handleCancel"
    >
      <div>
        <a-form :label-col="{ span: 5 }" :wrapper-col="{ span: 12 }" >
          <a-form-item >
            <a-input
              v-decorator="['note', { rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Entrer le nom du client!' }] }]"
              v-model="newcustomer"
            />
          </a-form-item>
        </a-form>
      </div>

    </a-modal>
    <CustomerCard v-bind:array-customers="customer" ></CustomerCard>
  </div>
</template>
```

the javascript :

```js
export default {
  components: {CustomerCard},
  layout: "dashboard",
  name: "DashboardHome",
  middleware: 'authenticated', //display page only for connected users

  data() {
    return {
      customer: [],
      visible: false,
      confirmLoading: false,
      newcustomer:"",
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.getAllCustomers();
  },


  methods: {

    showModal() {
      this.visible = true;
    },

    //when click on OK button, record the customer in api
    handleOk(e) {
      this.confirmLoading = true;
      axios
      .post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/customers', {
        name : this.newcustomer
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.visible = false;
        this.confirmLoading = false;
      }, 1000);
    },

    //click cancel button
    handleCancel(e) {
      console.log('Clicked cancel button');
      this.visible = false;
    },

    //get all customers in api
    getAllCustomers() {
      axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/customers')
        .then((res)=>{
          console.log(res.data['hydra:member'])
          this.customer = res.data['hydra:member']
          //this.totalStudies()
        }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
    }
```

So how can I reload the component CustomerCard when I post a customer ?
Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 0):

You could call `getAllCustomers()` in the `then` callback of `axios.post()`, which would refresh `customer` with the latest data from the database:

```js
axios.post(...).then(() => this.getAllCustomers())
```

Comment: Yes it works. But is it possible to do this without re doing an API call ?

I saw a solution with the key component but I don't know how to use it (https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/), any idea ?

Is it a potential good solution ?

Thanks

Comment: It's not so much a problem of rerendering the component because the data bound to the component would still be the same. It's the data you need to update, which would be rendered within the component. You could manually insert the new data into `customers` instead of making an API call.

Comment: Yes but when I do this : then(() => this.customer = this.customer.push(this.newcustomer)); (instead of then(() =>this.getAlleCustomers()))
It does not work. My children components says that he didn't retrieve the datas. I think it's because of the asychronous function ?

Comment: Oh I succeed to add new data in customer manually. But I dont know how to do to refresh the page with the new component added ?